# How to store ServerValue.TIMESTAMP as a string in Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, timestamp

I've an a firebase recyclerview and I want to query that datas in a OrderByChild for example TOPWEEK or TOPDAYS in order to that I planning to combin ServerValue.TIMESTAMP with star counts such as

> "Combin" : "1522741072_5"

first value is timestamp second value is star counts. but if I made this every time new one goes top, star counts is ignored (because of timestamp is in mili sec). I thinking that I should trim some value from timestamp. like this:

```
String.valueOf(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP).substring(0,4)
```

but it is not possible because I cant store timestamp as a string in firebase database. this is my model class

```
@Exclude
    public Map<String, Object> haritala() {
        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("yazar", yazar);
        result.put("baslik", baslik);
        result.put("uid",uid);
        result.put("favsays", favsays);
        result.put("fav", favori);
        result.put("mesajsays", mesajsays);
        result.put("mesaj", mesaj);
        result.put("Combin", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);   

        return result;
    }
```

Are there any solution

Comment: The `star counts` has a fixed value?

Comment: No it can increaseble or decreaseble by user

Comment: So to understand better, every time a user increases the counter you override this value `1522741072_5` with this `1522741072_6`, right?

Comment: yes, Alex mamo.

Answer (score 0):

According to your last comment, I understood that the `star counts` does not contains a fixed value, it can be incremented by users. In this case, your solution will not work. There is another solution to have two separate properties but unfortunately, Firebase Realtime database does not support queries on multiple properties, supports only queries on a single child property. Also you should **not** consider augmenting your data structure to allow a reverse lookup because in that case you'll have to many nodes.

If I were you, every time I should add a new item to the database, I'll use the `push()` method, which will generate as the key of the item, a random key which is based on time. So by default, all your items will be sorted by creation time. In this case, you'll only need to use a query that will look like this:

```
Query query = rootRef.child("results").orderByChild("reuslt");
```

Don't forget to set the value of `result` property as an `Integer` or as a `Long`, not as a `String` because in case of string the items are ordered `lexicographically`.

You can consider take a look at [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries), in which chained queries are permitted.